# remove/hide Layered Navigation when using static block only in Magento

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

When using option of 'Static block only' on the Category Page how can the Layered Navigation be hidden to create more room for the static blocks and then be visible if navigating to the same category page using a direct link in the url pointing to attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it through layout update

```
<reference name="left">
   <remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
</reference>
```